# How to get my listview to work in a new activity class

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, android-activity

I created an activity class called listView.class but it has an incompatible T upper bound error for listview and view. I also tried to change the name of my class to something else but still have the same error and I can't figure out how to solve this problem...

```
   enter coimport androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class ListView extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listview)
    }
}de here
```

Comment: please show us the error logcat
and how are you importing "import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity"

Comment: I haven't run the app yet so not sure of the logcat error but there is a red underline thing

Comment: I just thought that I would need to fix that problem first

Comment: remove "enter co" and spaces and debug the app again

Comment: I have just run my app and got the following error

Comment: where T is a type-variable:
    T extends View declared in method <T>findViewById(int)

Comment: I got it to work.. just making sure that my variable is not the same as the class but it can display the listview but there is a strange symbol shown such as the braces....